# Extending a probability measure from a semi-algebra to an algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

i'm involved in this exercise and i cannot figure out how to proceed. This is it:

> Let $P$ be a probability measure on the semi-algebra $S$. Then $P$ can be extended uniquely to a probability measure on the algebra $A$.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: HINT (in the case when $A$ is the algebra generated by $S$): it happens that $A$ is the set of finite disjoint unions of elements of $S$ (if you don't know this, you cannot prove anything). Then you simply define $$ P(S_1 \cup \dots \cup S_n)=P(S_1)+ \dots + P(S_n)$$ and show that it satisfies the axioms of probability.

Comment: @Crostul Thanks for your hint, but how can I prove it satisfies the axioms? It's easy for the null set but I don't know for the others.